# How to translate string to a current culture in a label of Windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to translate string to a current culture in a label of Windows forms?

```
    Format of the text to be displayed:
    <string in current culture> <string in english>

    ex: <welcome in dutch\french\chineese> <User ID in english>
---------------    
    string userid = "A123#"
    string str = String.Format(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, "{0} ", "Welcome");
    this.myLabel.Text =  str + userid ;
---------------
```

How can we do it?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the test code in the main post.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do exactly? If you want it to display French then you need to provide it a French translation, if you expect a way to provide automatic translation, what you want does not exist.  Your code seems incomplete please provide a sample that actually be compiled.

Comment: I want to translate the string "Welcome" to the current language of the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So built-in you're not getting translation but one approach would be to rely upon the ResourceManager to handle this for you by looking up the stored strings you want to display for each culture.  For each language you want to show, you could create a resource file that includes the culture value as part of the name - so something like:

```
myLangResource.es-CO.resx
myLangResource.fr-CA.resx
myLangResource.en-US.resx
```

Just add a new item of type Resource File to your project for each language you care about, then store off the strings you care about translating.  Those would have Names and Values in them which would be looked up by your code to retrieve the appropriate string.  Something like

```
Name       Value
-----------------
Welcome    Howdy
```

or

```
Name       Value
-----------------
Welcome    Bienvenido
```

Then, essentially, you create a CultureInfo member:

```
private CultureInfo curCulture;
```

and then set it to the current culture like so:

```
curCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Then you would load up the appropriate resource via a `ResourceManager` object to get the appropriate strings.  Something like so:

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("MyNamespace.myLangResource", typeof(DemoForm).Assembly);
string greeting = resourceManager.GetString("Welcome", curCulture);
// show the greeting however you want such as
myLabel.Text = greeting;
```

Let's assume you wanted to change the current culture value for some reason.  The resource lookup doesn't need the "es-CO" or "fr-CA" or "en-US" part of the name.  It'll automatically try to do this for you by looking for a resource file with the matching name.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-magic translation does not exist.

You can either:

- query on of translation services
- bring your own dictionary/translation engine with your code
- properly localize your application (provide multiple versions of resources and use them correspondingly).